# How to read comma separated values from a text file, then output result to a text file?

Tags: python, loops, csv

I need to create a program that will add numbers read from a text file separated by commas. i.e.

in `file.txt`:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

So far I have the simple code:

```
x = 1
y = 2
z = 3

sum = x + y + z

print(sum)
```

I'm not sure how I would assign each number in the text file to `x`, `y` and `z`.

What I would like is that it will iterate through each line in the text file, this would be with a simple loop.

However I also do not know how I would then output the results to another text file.
i.e. `answers.txt`:

```
6
15
24
```

Comment: So you seem to be looking for code that would read the CSV and compute the sum?

Answer (score 18):

You have the right idea going, let's start by opening some files:

```
with open("text.txt", "r") as filestream:
    with open("answers.txt", "w") as filestreamtwo:
```

Here, we have opened two filestreams - "text.txt" and "answers.txt".

Since we used `with`, these filestreams will automatically close after the code that is indented beneath them finishes running.

Now, let's run through the file "text.txt" line by line:

```
for line in filestream:
```

This will run a for loop and end at the end of the file.

Next, we need to change the input text into something we can work with, such as an array:

```
currentline = line.split(",")
```

Now, `currentline` contains all the integers listed in the first line of "text.txt".

Let's sum up these integers:

```
total = str(int(currentline[0]) + int(currentline[1]) + int(currentline [2])) + "\n"
```

We had to wrap each element in `currentline` with the `int` function around. Otherwise, instead of adding the integers, we would be concatenating strings!

Afterwards, we add the carriage return, `"\n"` in order to make "answers.txt" clearer to understand.

```
filestreamtwo.write(total)
```

Now, we are writing to the file "answers.txt"... That's it! You're done!

Here's the code again:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as filestream:
    with open("answers.txt", "w") as filestreamtwo:
        for line in filestream:
            currentline = line.split(",")
            total = str(int(currentline[0]) + int(currentline[1]) + int(currentline [2])) + "\n"
            filestreamtwo.write(total)
```

Comment: Hi l4mpi,

Thanks for the response, the OP stated they wanted the file output in a .txt format so I avoided using csv. I forgot about "for line in file", I will amend my answer with that now.  

I'm not familiar with "with", could you please respond with an example of how to open a filestream using "with", as the responses I have found online are very complex for me.

I have only used python, and as you've said, not very well. I originally came to stackoverflow to learn java, but I guess I might be better off spending more time in /python!

Comment: You seem to be confused - a csv file is just a normal text file, and you can save it with any ending you want including `.txt`. As for with statements in the context of files, you do `with open("myfile.txt") as f` and can then use the file object in the block of the with statement; it will be automatically closed after the block. See the other answers for examples of that.

Comment: Is this the best implementation? http://pastebin.com/6PyxetVz - Should I use map for the ints?

Comment: "The best" is somewhat subjective, but I'd say it's way better than your current code and definitely a good solution to OPs problem. Edit that in and you'll get an upvote :)

Comment: Maybe @EducateMe didn't write the best code but his patience and explanations seems great for beginners wanting to learn and we are in need of patient educators like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in fewer lines, but I hope you find this solution readable and easy to understand:

```
out = file('answers.txt', 'w')
for line in file('file.txt', 'r'):
    s = 0
    for num in line.strip().split(','):
        s += int(num)
    out.write("%d\n" % s)
```

Answer (score 0):

For this task you may want to not work with files in your program directly, but work with standard input (`input()` or `raw_input()` in Python 2) and standard output (just `print()`).

Then you specify input and output file names during invocation of your script:

```
python script.py < file.txt > answer.txt
```

With this scheme you can have a program like this (Python 2.7):

```
while (True):
    try:
        x, y, z = [int(val) for val in raw_input().split(',')]
        print (x + y + z)
    except EOFError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if the file has only comma separated values then why not save file as ".csv" format. If you can then:

You can always use a csv reader to read any CSV file as mentioned under the docs: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Quick example for your scenario:

```
with open('test.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    output_fil = open('output.txt', 'ab')
    for row in csvreader:
        result = 0
        for elem in row:
            result = result + int(elem)
        print result
        output_fil.writelines(str(result))
```

Where text.csv would contain input like:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
...
```

and output.txt shall contain:

```
6
15
..
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INFILE = "input.csv"
OUTFILE = "my.txt"

def row_sum(row, delim=","):
    try:
        return sum(int(i) for i in row.split(delim))
    except ValueError:
        return ""

with open(INFILE) as inf, open(OUTFILE, "w") as outf:
    outf.write("\n".join(str(row_sum(row)) for row in inf))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
with open("file2.txt","w") as f:
    print >> f,"\n".join(map(lambda x:str(sum(int(y) for y in x.split(","))),open("file1.txt")))
```

Comment: This is neither code nor answer golf. Downvoted as I don't consider your answer helpful, especially not for a new programmer.

Comment: Meh ask for code with little to no effort and I'll play golf... It looks to me like he spent more time writing his question than he did on his code ...