# Reading a file in python manipulating lines

Tags: python

So i have this file:

```
#Name, IdNb, Age, Direct, Fitness, Immune:
Bruno, cvd443, 37, <cvd221, cvd343, cvd245, cvd556>, 3, Yes 
Manuela, cvd256, 72, <cvd173, cvd132>, 4, No
```

I want to read it and create a list of lists and i coded this:

```
def readSocialNetwork (filename):

    inFile = open (filename, "r")
    fileContent = inFile.readlines()
    fileContent = fileContent [1:]

    socialNetworkList = []

    for line in fileContent:

        socialDetails = line.strip().split (", ")
        socialNetworkList.append(socialDetails) #socialNetworkObject

    return socialNetworkList
```

And it returns this:

```
[['Bruno', 'cvd443', '37', '<cvd221', 'cvd343', 'cvd245', 'cvd556>', '3', 'Yes'], ['Manuela', 'cvd256', '72', '<cvd173', 'cvd132>', '4', 'No']]
```

The only problem is i want the info between < > to be all together inside the same string, but because of the split function it doesnt happen. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is a perfect application for the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html) library

Comment: Do you want the commas `"<cvd221, cvd343, cvd245, cvd556>"` or `"<cvd221 cvd343 cvd245 cvd556>"`?  Additionally, are all the spaces also in the file?

Comment: Yes with the commas!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Read comma separated values from a text file, then output result to text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744804/python-read-comma-separated-values-from-a-text-file-then-output-result-to-tex)

Comment: That’s only one question on reading comma separated data, there are many many more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the csv library to parse the comma-separated values (csv) file:

```
import csv


def read_csv(filename):
    with open(filename) as stream:
        next(stream)  # skip the first line
        csv_reader = csv.reader(stream, skipinitialspace=True)
        return list(csv_reader)


for stuff in read_csv("data.csv"):
    print(stuff)
```

Output:

```
['Bruno', 'cvd443', '37', '<cvd221', 'cvd343', 'cvd245', 'cvd556>', '3', 'Yes ']
['Manuela', 'cvd256', '72', '<cvd173', 'cvd132>', '4', 'No']
```

## Update

My initial solution was dead wrong. In my revised solution, I added quotes around the < and >:

```
import csv


def translate(lines):
    for line in lines:
        yield line.replace('<', '"<').replace('>', '>"')

def read_csv(filename):
    with open(filename) as stream:
        next(stream)  # Skip the first line
        stream = translate(stream)
        csv_reader = csv.reader(stream, skipinitialspace=True)
        return list(csv_reader)


for stuff in read_csv("data.csv"):
    print(stuff)
```

Output:

```
['Bruno', 'cvd443', '37', '<cvd221, cvd343, cvd245, cvd556>', '3', 'Yes ']
['Manuela', 'cvd256', '72', '<cvd173, cvd132>', '4', 'No']
```

The translate function takes a bunch of lines, then add the quotes around the < and >.

Answer (score 0):

*The easiest solution is to use a standardized file format such as CSV*. If you can't do that, you'll need a regular expression. Here's on that works on your sample input:

```
(?:\s|^)(?:([^<].*?)(?:,|\n|$)|<(.*?)>(?:,|\n|$))
```

Here's how it works:

- `(?:\s|^)` matches the beginning of the input or a whitespace token (ignored)
- `(?:` opens a non-capturing group that's going to contain our two match options
- `([^<].*?)(?:,|\n|$)` matches and captures content that's not surrounded by `<>`, and is followed by a comma, newline, or string end.
- `|` or, since our non-capturing group has two options
- `<(.*?)>(?:,|\n|$)` matches and captures content that's surrounded by `<>`, and is followed by a comma, newline, or string end.
- `)` closes the non-capturing group containing the new options.

Note this doesn't handle comment lines, I'll leave that to you to figure out as I'm a strong believer in being able to work with your own code base.

Comment: @robinsax maybe adding a few `*` to account for either non spaced CSV or multiple spaces `(?:\s*|^)(?:\s*([^<].*?)(?:,|\n|$)|<(.*?)>(?:,|\n|$))`.

https://regex101.com/r/aGqEMG/1