# How do I slice data from a text file with a prefix in Python?

Tags: python

I was wondering if I could slice data from a txt file using a prefix for example:

```python
f = open("file.txt", "r")
print(f.read())
```

Let's say for example's sake there is only 1 line and that line is "21:days" the prefix here is ":" and I want to make Python understand that data on the left of the prefix which is ":" is x and data on the right is y.

I am aware of the split function but I want to process a text file and I don't know how to split it according to something like this

Edit:
An example of an input I would like to process is "39!@:Option2", this is going to be looped to every line in the text file which has a similar format.

An example of the expected output is:

```python
391!@ requested Option2
```

Comment: Please show more examples of your data and some expected outputs. What type or format of your desired output? Is the format ,"x:y" consistency for every line?

Comment: You seem to be aware of the `split` method. What have you tried with it? Seems like a simple `x, y = line.split(':')` is what you are looking for,,,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Read comma separated values from a text file, then output result to text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744804/python-read-comma-separated-values-from-a-text-file-then-output-result-to-tex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people use pandas library when processing data like this.

Reading data from a text file separated with special characters is a normal procedure using python. These files with plain text are known as Character Separated Values ​​(CSV) which use a special character to identify the different information that the file contains. Using the pandas library is one of the most common ways to process the information contained in these files.

Here is how you would do it with your file separated with ":"

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file.txt", sep = ":", names=['User', 'Option'])
```

To access the information you will only need to point to the data contained in the dataframe created, like so: `y = df['User'][0]` This will get you the value in the first row of the column *User*. To get an output like the one you've presented in your example, you could just use something like: `print(df['User'][0] + " requested " + df['Option'][0])` which will return:

```
391!@ requested Option2
```

Consider that this way of accessing information is optimized to read multiple lines in a text file. That way, you'll have all the information contained in a dataframe separated in rows and columns.

Processing data like this will avoid you having to loop through the entire file using *split*

Comment: Frankly, pandas is quite an overkill for this usecase. At best, the built-in library `csv` can be used, but a simple loop on the file can suffice here...